# Rails view without application.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I`m now developing RoR app and have one problem. In application.html i have sidebar. that i would like to disable in some views in different controller.

```
render :layout => false
```

option in hellper isn`t that i need in this situation. What will be the best option in this case? 
Also tried to load specific css

```
def controller_stylesheet
    controller_name = controller.dash
    if File.exists?( "/assets/dash.css" )
      stylesheet_link_tag( 'dash' )
```

worst case i will copy that sidebar to controller views were i would like to display it, but i want some good solution for this, not this bad one.

Comment: Unless you're putting files in a root directory on your server called `/assets`, which is totally insane, you're probably looking in the wrong spot. Maybe you want: `Rails.root.join('assets/stylesheets/dash.css')`?

Comment: Thank you. But it loads application and dash stylesheets together, but in that specific controler i need to load without applications css

Comment: In case you want to just display the sidebar in some views, create a _sidebar.html.erb partial and <%= render 'sidebar' %> in the views you want?

Comment: Awesome. Just what i need :)